# Emberjs models with relations throws an error: "Cannot set property 'store' of undefined"

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying out ember at my work to see if we should use it for our future applications I am doing a simple test application and I wanted to try out the relations between the models. This is the code I have that defines the models:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('index', {path: "/"}, function () {
        this.resource("config", {path: "/config/:config_id"});
    });
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend();

App.Conf = DS.Model.extend({
    module : DS.attr(),
    reports: DS.hasMany('report'),
    isClean: function() {
        return !this.get('reports').isAny('isClean', false);
    }.property('reports.@each')
});


App.Report = DS.Model.extend({
    country: DS.attr(),
    google_account_id: DS.attr(),
    web_property_id: DS.attr(),
    custom_source_uid: DS.attr(),
    isClean: function() {
        return (
                this.get('country') != '' &&
                this.get('google_account_id') != '' &&
                this.get('web_property_id') != '' &&
                this.get('custom_source_uid') != ''
                );
    }.property('country', 'google_account_id', 'web_property_id', 'custom_source_uid')
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://playground.loc/battle_of_frameworks/json.php'
});
```

…and here is the JSON that is being loaded:

[image]

The error I get is:

> Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot set property 'store' of undefined

I Googled the problem and it's usually something about naming your models in plural (ie: App.Reports) which I'm not doing. So I am not sure what the problem is here. Can anyone give any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your code.

Your server doesn't provide the payload expected by Ember Data. I would recommend reading [this document](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#rest-adapter-and-serializer-configuration) about customizing your serializer if you can't generate the proper json payload with your backend.

Ember.js is all about convention over configuration. Right now, you are not following those conventions:

- attributes are camelcased

  ```
  App.Report = DS.Model.extend({
      googleAccountId: DS.attr() //instead of google_account_id
  });
  ```
- you don't need to create the index route, [it comes for free in Ember](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/). So your router should simply look like:

  `App.Router.map(function () {
      this.resource("config", {path:    "/config/:config_id"});
  });`
- Are you sure that your backend expects the `Config` to be served from `/config/:config_id` and not `/configs/:config_id` ?
- You declare a `config` resource. The convention is to have a `App.Config` model and not `App.Conf`

In order to clean your code, you can also take advantage of computed properties to DRY your code:

```
App.Report = DS.Model.extend({
  country: DS.attr(),
  googleAccountId: DS.attr(),
  webPropertyId: DS.attr(),
  customSourceUid: DS.attr(),
  isClean: Ember.computed.and('country', 'googleAccountId', 'webPropertyId', 'customSourceUid')
});
```

You also need to pay attention when defining a computed property based on an array. The `isClean` of `Config` uses `isClean` of `Report` but your computed property observes only the elements of your `Report` association. The correct way of writing it is:

```
App.Config = DS.Model.extend({
  module : DS.attr(),
  reports: DS.hasMany('report'),
  isClean: function() {
    return !this.get('reports').isAny('isClean', false);
  }.property('reports.@each.isClean')  //make sure to invalidate your computed property when `isClean` changes
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I added all of the changes you suggested me and I changed the json format. Cheers!